# How To Return Nested Variable?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, return, return-value

I don't know how to RETURN variable from the following function.

Here is the code...

```
downloadData.setOnClickListener {

            val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
            handler.post {
                val fetchData =
                    FetchData("http://localhost/xampp/CRM/PHP/show_contacts_db.php")

                if (fetchData.startFetch()) {
                    if (fetchData.onComplete()) {
                        val result = fetchData.data.toString()
                        
                        Log.i("FetchData", result)
                        

                        val companyName = result.substringAfter("Name: ").substringBefore(";")
                        showContactName.text = "${companyName}"
                        val companyNumber = result.substringAfter("Number: ").substringBefore(";")
                        showContactNumber.text = "${companyNumber}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**companyName** and **companyNumber** needed to be returned so I can use it in other places.

When I Try to use `Return companyNumber` I have a message that "return" is not allowed here.

Comment: Have a look [at this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value/70178210#70178210). Generally a good approach would be to pass those values to another function that handles processing them rather than returning them, or set them as class members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally with lambdas, you don't explicitly `return` a value - the lambda returns the value of the last expression. Using your code as an example (it won't actually work but we'll get to that!):

```
handler.post {
    ...
    companyNumber
}
```

which is the same as how things like `map` calls take a transformation function

```
listOf(1, 2, 3).map { it * 2 }
```

that's just doubling each number, but the result is being implicitly returned and stored in the resulting list, right? And it lets you chain lambdas together, since each one evaluates to a value (which might be `Unit` if it "doesn't return a result")

If you want, you *can* explicitly use what's called a *qualified return*:

```
handler.post {
    ...
    return@post companyNumber
}
```

where you're naming the function call you're returning to.

[Kotlin docs: returning a value from a lambda expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#returning-a-value-from-a-lambda-expression)

---

Also if you want to return two values, you can't do that - so you'll have to bundle them up in a single object. You could just return a `Pair`, or create a data class that's more readable:

```
return@post Pair(companyName, companyNumber)

//or
data class CompanyDeets(val name: String, val number: String)
...
return@post CompanyDeets(companyName, companyNumber)
```

---

**But** aside from how you do it in general, why do you want to return anything here? `Handler#post` takes a `Runnable` which returns nothing (`void` in Java), and `View.OnClickListener#onClick` doesn't return anything either.

Neither of them would do anything with a value you returned - and if you explicitly return a value, that means your lambda's signature **doesn't match** (right now it's implicitly returning `Unit` to match what's expected by the caller), and you'll get an error

What you probably want to do instead, is create a function inside your class (`Activity` or whatever) that uses your data, something like `fun doSomethingWith(companyName: String, companyNumber: String)` and call that inside your lambda. That's way you're executing code in reaction to a click

Answer (score 0):

just declare var Company Name in global, or create a function with that params

var companyName: String? = null

handler.post {
...
companyName = result.substringAfter("Name: ").substringBefore(";")
}

OR

handler.post {
...
save(result.substringAfter("Name: ").substringBefore(";"))
}

fun save(companyName: String){ ... }